# Change column equation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using MS SQL Server and I have a multiple columns and databases already made.  3 of these columns in one database called Inventory are: CaseQuantity, UnitsQuantity, and TotalUnits.  How do I change it that the TotalUnits column becomes (CaseQuanity * 12) + UnitsQuantity?

I am new to this. Thank you so much for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: What is `TotalQuantity`? A new column? it's not listed in your "3 columns" list.

Comment: please select a single tag for your RDBMS... not 3 :/

Comment: Are you attempting to create a new column on the table (note you called it a database, it sounds like you're actually talking about tables).  Are you looking to just have a new column within a select statement?

Comment: Sorry TotalQuantity and TotalUnits are supposed to be the same.  I just want to make the existing TotalUnits column equal to  (CaseQuanity * 12) + UnitsQuantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add a new computed column to your existing table, you could use `ALTER TABLE` like this to do that:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table --change this to your tablename
ADD TotalQuantity AS (CaseQuantity * 12) + UnitsQuantity  PERSISTED
```

If you just want to select a new `computed` column, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT CaseQuantity
    ,UnitsQuantity
    ,TotalUnits
    ,(CaseQuantity * 12) + UnitsQuantity AS TotalQuantity  
FROM your_table       --change this to your tablename
```

If you are looking to recreate your table with a new computed column then you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
(
CaseQuantity int
,UnitsQuantity int
,TotalUnits int
,TotalQuantity AS (CaseQuantity * 12) + UnitsQuantity  PERSISTED 
)
```

> **Persisted**
>
> You may have noticed that I also used the property "Persisted" for the
>   computed column. This property for computed columns has been
>   introduced in SQL Server 2005 and onwards. It is important for any
>   computed column, because many additional features depend on it. To be
>   able to make a computed column as Persisted it has to be
>   deterministic.
>
> Here are a few rules:
>
> - If Persisted property is off then calculated column will be just a virtual column. No data for this column will be stored on disk and
>     values will be calculated every time when referenced in a script. If
>     this property is set active then data of computed column will be
>     stored on disk.
> - Any update in referenced column will be synchronized automatically in computed column if it is Persisted.
> - Along with some other conditions Persisted is required to create an index on the computed column.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b83c/1/0)

Comment: What if I want change the existing Column TotalUnits to  (CaseQuanity * 12) + UnitsQuantity?

Comment: @LeoOsman I would just drop the existing column from the table and use the alter table statement above to recreate the TotalUnits column. Here is the query to drop your column: `ALTER TABLE your_table
DROP COLUMN TotalQuantity;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Computed Columns in a Table. TotalUnits columns should be not inserted. It is computed to other columns.
More detail to refer this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx